# When loading multiple html5 video's, IE9 crashes and IE10&11 don't load all of the video's correctly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-video, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I have a bunch of html5-video's on my page that where I only preload the metadata.
With Javascript I then load the videos (videoElement.load();).

This seems to cause IE9 to crash...

IE10 & 11 don't crash, but half of the movies aren't loaded correctly.
All the videos do return the canPlayTrough event, witch confuses me more.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you debug I strongly suggest using the following, recommended by the MSDN blog.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].error.code
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2011/07/20/html5-video-not-working-in-ie9-some-tips-to-debug.aspx

> MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED : 1
>
> The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user.
>
> MEDIA_ERR_DECODE : 3
>
> An error has occurred in the decoding of the media resource, after the resource was
>   established to be usable.
>
> MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK : 2 
>   A network error has caused the user agent to stop fetching the media resource, after the 
>   resource was established to be usable
>
> MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : 4 
>   The media resource specified by src was not usable.

We can't really debug this for you if we don't have the code you are using, or the files you are trying to display. The above, however, should be able to tell you what is going wrong.

== Edit to extend ==

If you are having issue #3, you are likely breaking IE's memory management. What is likely happening is that IE is attempting to pre-load the videos into memory and then crashes when resources run out. You can fix this by destroying the video elements as they are no longer needed, and turning off preloading.

Comment: Hi, the errorcode I get is "3"... The problem starts to occur if you add 14+ movies on one page.

Comment: Most likely then, it is an available-memory-resource issue on the page. IE likely loads the images into memory in a way that they are competing for scarce resources, and fail hard once they run out. The solutions this to range from better compression, to turning off pre-load. Esentially you'll need to make it so IE isn't making all the videos compete for memory at page-load time.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the case. We are now aiming for smaller and better compressed video's, witch already has it effect.

Answer (score 0):

The crash must be because IE sucks.
If some of the videos dont load it might be that the browser dont support the encoding.
You need to send the files with the correct MIME type end encode the video with a supported encoding.
If you give a link to the page i might be able to figure out whats wrong.